# Write LaTeX section title to an additional file

Tags: sectioning, external-files

I have a book that comes with an answer manual.  So when I define a section or subsection I want to also write the name of that to the file containing the answers.  Thus, I want to end with this type of thing in `bookans.tex`.

```
\subsection{One.I.1: Gauss' Method}
\begin{ans}{One.I.1.17}
      We can perform Gauss' method can in different ways ..
```

(I write to that file using the *answers* package.)  I see in the LaTeX source that the last thing in argument 6 to `\@startsection`, the *style*, can be a command that takes an argument, so I tried variations on this.

```
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection
   {subsection}{2}{0em}{-10ex plus1ex minus1ex}{1em}%
   {\raggedright\usefont{T1}{fvs}{b}{n}\large\SetSectioningName}}

\def\SetSectioningName#1{\gdef\sectioningname{#1}%
  \typeout{SUBSECTION\space START:\space\sectioningname}}
```

But it does not get the name; it gets  "`\setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {{\hskip 0em\relax I.1\hskip 1em\relax \relax }}\hangindent \wd \@tempboxa \noindent \box \@tempboxa \interlinepenalty \@M Gauss' Method\@@par`".  Then, for instance, *hyperref* gets annoyed at the section title.

To write the Chapter name I modified `\@chapter`. Do I need to do the same torturous thing with the sectioning commands (maybe `\@sect`)?  It seems perilous to me; for instance, what if the LaTeX3 folks change those definitions?

Answer (score 4):

Probably the easiest thing would be to redefine `\addcontentsline` as all the sectioning commands pretty much do something like

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
```

as long as tocdepth is set suitably.
You could make that write to the toc and your additional file.

Comment: Thank you David.  I take your comment to confirm that I haven't overlooked a natural way to do it.  I use that command to do a number of things so I'll have to think about if I can modify it to this purpose.  Thanks, Jim

Comment: Just remember to redefine `\addcontentsline` *before* loading `hyperref`, because this package redefines it adding to the existent functionality.